# I add <!DOCTYPE html> and it breaks my code and without it it work perfectly

Tags: javascript, css, html

Every time i add  the rats at the top dont fall down. I saw other people had this problem and it had to do with adding px to certain things. i have that in some of my code but i have no clue where else it needs it.

CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>

<title>Balloons Toss</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<meta name="Author" content="Tyler Chretien" />
<meta name="Author" content="Karishma" />
<meta name="Author" content="Eric Nguygen" />

<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<style>


#SPAN_1:hover{color:blue;}
#SPAN_1{color:black;}

#SPAN_2:hover{color:blue;}
#SPAN_2{color:black;}

table.center {
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
width: 560px;
text-align: center;
}


@font-face{
font-family: memes;
src: url(DeterminationSansWeb.woff);
}

body{
font-family: memes, sans-serif;
background-color: black;
}

.blackbox{
color: white;
width: 300px;
}

td{
height: 900px;
}

img, body{
-khtml-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

img {
-webkit-user-drag: none;
-khtml-user-drag: none;
-moz-user-drag: none;
-o-user-drag: none;
}
</style>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
var numberOfMonster= 0, setupScore, setupMonster, names=["rat.gif"],             
catleft = 325, catright= 250, ratleft, ratright, countElement, howfast= 
10, score = 0;

/*This function is the initial setup for the game aka score, sound,     
monster spawn */
function myFunction()
{
spawntheMonster( 0 );
document.all.coolscore.innerHTML= 0;
setupScore=setInterval(function(){score++;             
document.all.coolscore.innerHTML=score;}, 1000 );
setupMonster=setInterval(function(){spawntheMonster( 0 );}, 3000 );
document.getElementById('sound').play();
}

 /*Next four function are deticated for moving the cat and setting 
 boundaries */
 function leftArrowPressed()
 {
  var element = document.getElementById("cat"); 

  if(parseInt(element.style.right.substring(element.style.right.length 
- 2 , 0 )) > 0 ) {
        element.style.right = parseInt(element.style.right) - 
20 + 'px';          
  }

 }         

 function rightArrowPressed() 
 {
   var element = document.getElementById("cat");


  if(parseInt(element.style.right.substring(element.style.right.length - 
  2 
  , 0 )) < 480 ) {
          element.style.right = parseInt(element.style.right) 
  + 20 + 'px';
     }
  }

function upArrowPressed() 
 {
    var element = document.getElementById("cat");

    if(parseInt(element.style.top.substring(element.style.top.length - 2 
, 
   0 )) > 0 ) {
           element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 
   20 + 'px';
    }
   }

   function downArrowPressed() 
   {
    var element = document.getElementById("cat");


   if(parseInt(element.style.top.substring(element.style.top.length - 2 , 
   0 )) < 740 ) {
           element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 
   20 + 'px';
    }
    }

   /* connects the id's of arrow keys and w,a,s,d to the previous 
  functions to be able to move  */  
  function movetheguy(event){
switch (event.keyCode) {
       case 39:
         leftArrowPressed();
         break;

       case 37:
         rightArrowPressed();
         break;

       case 38:
          upArrowPressed();
          break;

       case 40:
          downArrowPressed();
          break;

       case 68:
          leftArrowPressed();
          break;

       case 65:
          rightArrowPressed();
          break;

        case 87:
           upArrowPressed();
           break;

        case 83:
           downArrowPressed();
           break;
}
}

 /* sets spawn, attributes, and clickablity of the rats */
 function spawntheMonster(monster){

var widthrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 112 )* 5 - 20;
widthrandom     = "position:absolute; right: "+widthrandom+"; top: 
 000;";
var z           = document.createElement("IMG"); 

z.setAttribute("src", names[monster]);
z.setAttribute("style", widthrandom);
z.setAttribute("width", "40");
z.setAttribute("height", "54");
z.setAttribute("id", numberOfMonster+"mon");
z.setAttribute("onLoad", "setInterval(moveguydown, 100, this);");
z.setAttribute("onClick", "this.style.top=parseInt(this.style.top)-75;");

document.getElementById("back1").appendChild(z);
numberOfMonster++;
 }

/* moves the rats */
function moveguydown(moveMonster){

if(parseInt(moveMonster.style.top)>= 900 ){
    moveMonster.style.top= -500;
    moveMonster.style.right=Math.floor(Math.random() * 112 )* 5 - 
  20;  //check this
}
else
    moveMonster.style.top=parseInt(moveMonster.style.top)+howfast;
    overlap(moveMonster);
 }

  /* randomly spawns the rats */
 function randomspawn(){

spawntheMonster(Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length));
}


  /* This function displays the end screen and resets game*/
   function die(){
var highscore=document.all.coolscore.innerHTML;
var count;
for(count= 0 ; count<numberOfMonster; count++){
    countElement=document.getElementById(count+"mon");
    document.getElementById("back1").removeChild(countElement);
}

numberOfMonster = 0;
document.all.coolscore.innerHTML=
"GAME OVER<br><span onClick='location.reload();'>Click to restart! 
  </span><br>SCORE: "+score+
"<font size='5'><br>Thanks to<br>Cat By: PRguitarman<br>Sound By: Jay 
   Man<br>Rats By: Yacht Club Games";
clearInterval(setupScore);
clearInterval(setupMonster);
 }

 /* Compares hit boxes and checks to see if you die */
 function overlap(obj){
catleft =parseInt(cat.style.right)+ 75;
catright=parseInt(cat.style.right);
ratleft =parseInt(obj.style.right)+parseInt(obj.width);
ratright=parseInt(obj.style.right);

cattop =parseInt(cat.style.top);
catbot=parseInt(cat.style.top)+ 150;
rattop =parseInt(obj.style.top)+parseInt(obj.height);
ratbottom=parseInt(obj.style.top);  

 if(rattop<catbot && ratbottom>cattop && ratright<catleft && 
ratleft>catright)

    die();


}

 /* Switches difficulty and sound */
 function twospeeds(){

if(howfast== 30 ){//fast
        back1.style.backgroundImage="url('large0.gif')";
        howfast= 10;}
if(howfast== 10){//WAY too fast
        back1.style.backgroundImage="url('large2.gif')";
        howfast= 30;
        document.getElementById('sound').src="sun.mp3";
        document.getElementById('sound').play();
        }
  }

 </script>
 </head>
```

html

```
<body onKeyDown="" onkeyup="movetheguy(event);" >

<table class="center" style="position: relative;">
 <tbody><tr>
 <td id="back1"  style="vertical-align: text-top; font-size:400%; 
 background- 
image: url('large0.gif'); position: relative;">

    <div class = "no-copy" id="coolscore">
        <span onclick="myFunction();" id="SPAN_1">CLICK HERE 
 TO START</span>
        <span onclick="twospeeds();" id="SPAN_2" style="font- 
 size:42px;">Click here for Insane mode</span>
        <span style="font-size:24px;"><br>Use the Arrow Keys 
  or WASD to move<br>Click on the rats to move them up</span>
    </div>


<br><br><br><br><img alt = "cat" src="cat.gif" width="75" height="150" 
  id="cat" style="position: absolute; right: 250px; top: 500px">

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<audio id="sound" hidden src="sound.mp3" >
</audio>
<audio id="sound2" hidden src="sun.mp3" >
</audio>
<footer style="border-top: 1px solid blue">
 <a href="http://elvis.rowan.edu/~chretient7/"
title="Link to my home page">
Tyler Chretien
</a>

<span style="float: right;">
<a href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer">HTML5</a> /
<a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer?profile=css3">
CSS3 </a>
</span>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

https://github.com/Crouton18/game/blob/master/balloon.html

You can check by removing the  in the code how it suppose to work. But in general the rats need to be falling down and when the cat gets hit the game ends.

Comment: I know it's hard to avoid when you're learning, but this is a classic example of why copy-pasting code from different sources without a clear understanding of what it does is bad...

Comment: the only thing i copied pasted was the arrowkey functions and css stuff. The arrowkeys arent even the problem and the css i had to change it from html bc the way i had it was outdatted.

Comment: What I mean is that you're mixing and matching HTML 4 and HTML 5 by having `<!DOCTYPE html>` *and* a ns declaration on your html tag. You either need to use HTML 4 correctly as in Jack Bash's answer or better yet eliminate the ns declaration and just use HTML 5 as in kaiido's answer. I assumed that you achieved that mixing and matching by copy-pasting HTML from different sources.

Comment: Ignore both answers - they're nonsense. Looks like you're missing a "px" unit on some of your positioning styles. E.g. `moveMonster.style.top= -500;`

Answer (score 2):

Because the HTML tag is XHTML. Use this doctype instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: in validator.w3.or it gives Error: Obsolete doctype. Expected <!DOCTYPE html>. From line 1, column 1; to line 1, column 90 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">↩<html